# How do I use Grunt to change a Requirejs config setting?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs

I'm precompiling Handlebars templates and loading them through Requirejs.

Grunt creates a build and does all the precompiling and whatnot.

Next step is to use Handlebars Runtime instead of the full Handlebars script.

In the RequireJS config, the path to Handlebars is set:

`js/src/config.js`:

```
require.config({
    //...
    paths: { handlebars: 'lib/handlebars' }
    //...
});
```

For a particular Grunt task, I wish to include an option that will change this path to `handlebars.runtime`, so that when the whole thing is compressed into a single file it only has the runtime version of Handlebars.

The config that gets included into the build would therefore be:

```
require.config({
    //...
    paths: { handlebars: 'lib/handlebars.runtime' }
    //...
});
```

Is this possible? Is there a better of way achieving the same result?

Comment: You can create your own grunt task.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass options to grunt tasks - is this what you want to do?

```
grunt myTask --myOption value
```

which is then available in your grunt config for that task (in your case require) like so:

```
grunt.option('myOption')
```